# Problem with connect facebookads library for extract data from Facebook with Marketing API using Python

Tags: facebook, api

I want to get info about ad campaign. And I start from this code to get campaign name. and I get this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/win7/PycharmProjects/API_Facebook/dd.py", line 2, in <module>
    from facebookads.adobjects.adaccount import AdAccount
  File "C:\Users\win7\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\facebookads\adobjects\adaccount.py", line 1582
    def get_insights(self, fields=None, params=None, async=False, batch=None, pending=False):
                                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
                                                     ^
```

What is may be reason? and if you want, can give code examples how can I get more info about campaign?
[Click here to view image: code and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gh0Nq.png)

Comment: Please go read [ask]. Code relevant to your question belongs directly into your question, not just dumped on an external site. Please go check https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361/10283047, and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: This is weird. [According to the sdk](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-python-business-sdk/blob/master/facebook_business/adobjects/adaccount.py#L3181), the method interface is different. That might mean you have an old, buggy version. I'm not that familiar with Python - maybe try removing the `C:\Users\win7\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\facebookads\` directory?

Comment: To clarify, the issue is coming from the import, not from any of the code you wrote. You may want to edit your question to reflect that.

Comment: @KevinHoerr Thanks! I also think the problem is this, but I tried to remove it and reinstall it did not help.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Python 3.7, use `async_`, not only `async`.

```
import os, re
path = r"path facebookads"
python_files = []

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):

for filename in filenames:
if filename.endswith(".py"):
            python_files.append(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
    for filename in filenames:
        if filename.endswith(".py"):
            python_files.append(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))

for python_file in python_files:

    with open(python_file, "r") as f:
        text = f.read()
        revised_text = re.sub("async", "async_", text)

    with open(python_file, "w") as f:
        f.write(revised_text)
```

Comment: Please submit the answer directly in the Stack Overflow answer. Links may be useful but are not an answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

They updated and renamed the library, now it's [facebook_ads](https://pypi.org/project/facebook-business/) and `async` argument was renamed to `is_async`

Answer (score 0):

Try updating facebookads:

```
$ pip install --upgrade facebookads
```

I'm using facebookads==2.11.4.

More info: https://pypi.org/project/facebookads/