# I am getting an error when using the facebook api

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

```
 File "SAMPLE_CODE.py", line 21, in <module>
    from facebookads.adobjects.adaccount import AdAccount
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/facebookads/adobjects/adaccount.py", line 1582
    def get_insights(self, fields=None, params=None, async=False, batch=None, pending=False):
                                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am trying to use the Facebook API and I am getting this error. Not sure what to do about it. This is my first time setting up and trying to use this API. Any help would be appreciated

Here is the file I am trying to run

"""python

```
# Copyright 2014 Facebook, Inc.

# You are hereby granted a non-exclusive, worldwide, royalty-free license to
# use, copy, modify, and distribute this software in source code or binary
# form for use in connection with the web services and APIs provided by
# Facebook.

# As with any software that integrates with the Facebook platform, your use
# of this software is subject to the Facebook Developer Principles and
# Policies [http://developers.facebook.com/policy/]. This copyright notice
# shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the software.

# THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
# IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
# FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL
# THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
# LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING
# FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER
# DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.

from facebookads.adobjects.adaccount import AdAccount
from facebookads.adobjects.adsinsights import AdsInsights
from facebookads.api import FacebookAdsApi

access_token = 'token'
ad_account_id = 'id'
app_secret = 'secret'
app_id = 'id'
FacebookAdsApi.init(access_token=access_token)

fields = [
    'reach',
    'delivery',
    'cost_per_result',
    'cpp',
    'cpm',
    'cost_per_action_type:page_engagement',
    'purchase_roas:omni_purchase',
    'website_purchase_roas:offsite_conversion_fb_pixel_purchase',
    'mobile_app_purchase_roas:app_custom_event_fb_mobile_purchase',
    'campaign_group_name',
]
params = {
    'level': 'ad',
    'filtering': [{'field':'delivery_info','operator':'IN','value':['active']}],
    'breakdowns': ['days_1'],
    'time_range': {'since':'2019-11-14','until':'2019-11-21'},
}
print(AdAccount(ad_account_id).get_insights(
    fields=fields,
    params=params,
))
```

"""

Here is another stack overflow question where async= False is the error too

[Problem with connect facebookads library for extract data from Facebook with Marketing API using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52855490/problem-with-connect-facebookads-library-for-extract-data-from-facebook-with-mar)

Could someone explain what is going on here ?

Thanks

I downloaded version 3.6 of Python using pyenv and Homebrew and tried to run the file again but I got a new error code.

"""

```
Kiefer's Macbook Pro:facebook-python-business-sdk kiefergallant$ python3.6 SAMPLE_CODE.py 
/Users/kiefergallant/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/facebookads/utils/api_utils.py:30: UserWarning: value of breakdowns might not be compatible.  Expect list<breakdowns_enum>;  got <class 'list'>
  warnings.warn(message)
/Users/kiefergallant/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/facebookads/utils/api_utils.py:30: UserWarning: insights does not allow field delivery
  warnings.warn(message)
/Users/kiefergallant/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/facebookads/utils/api_utils.py:30: UserWarning: insights does not allow field cost_per_result
  warnings.warn(message)
/Users/kiefergallant/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/facebookads/utils/api_utils.py:30: UserWarning: insights does not allow field cost_per_action_type:page_engagement
  warnings.warn(message)
/Users/kiefergallant/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/facebookads/utils/api_utils.py:30: UserWarning: insights does not allow field purchase_roas:omni_purchase
  warnings.warn(message)
/Users/kiefergallant/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/facebookads/utils/api_utils.py:30: UserWarning: insights does not allow field website_purchase_roas:offsite_conversion_fb_pixel_purchase
  warnings.warn(message)
/Users/kiefergallant/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/facebookads/utils/api_utils.py:30: UserWarning: insights does not allow field mobile_app_purchase_roas:app_custom_event_fb_mobile_purchase
  warnings.warn(message)
/Users/kiefergallant/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/facebookads/utils/api_utils.py:30: UserWarning: insights does not allow field campaign_group_name
  warnings.warn(message)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SAMPLE_CODE.py", line 51, in <module>
    params=params
  File "/Users/kiefergallant/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/facebookads/adobjects/adaccount.py", line 1639, in get_insights
    return request.execute()
  File "/Users/kiefergallant/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/facebookads/api.py", line 664, in execute
    cursor.load_next_page()
  File "/Users/kiefergallant/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/facebookads/api.py", line 851, in load_next_page
    params=self.params,
  File "/Users/kiefergallant/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/facebookads/api.py", line 332, in call
    raise fb_response.error()
facebookads.exceptions.FacebookRequestError: 

  Message: Call was not successful
  Method:  GET
  Path:    https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/act_423073558387349/insights
  Params:  {'level': 'ad', 'filtering': '[{"field":"delivery_info","operator":"IN","value":["active"]}]', 'breakdowns': '["days_1"]', 'time_range': '{"since":"2019-11-14","until":"2019-11-21"}', 'fields': 'reach,delivery,cost_per_result,cpp,cpm,cost_per_action_type:page_engagement,purchase_roas:omni_purchase,website_purchase_roas:offsite_conversion_fb_pixel_purchase,mobile_app_purchase_roas:app_custom_event_fb_mobile_purchase,campaign_group_name'}

  Status:  400
  Response:
    {
      "error": {
        "message": "(#2635) You are calling a deprecated version of the Ads API. Please update to the latest version: v5.0.",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 2635,
        "fbtrace_id": "AASs5AEHjZ0VOZrOfeNziJy"
      }
    }
```

"""

Comment: Hi, could you please show us your source-code? Otherwise, we cant help you much.

Comment: Where can I find the source code? do you want the file with the error? It's a file I downloaded from facebook

Comment: Yes, The 'SAMPLE_CODE.py' file.

Comment: Ok I just edited the post with the source code

Comment: _"Here is the file I am trying to run"_ - that does not appear to be the file the error message is talking about: _"File `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/facebookads/adobjects/adaccount.py`, line 1582"_

Comment: You probably want to remove your token and ids from the source code. Edit: When sharing it online, not in your actual source code.

Comment: Do you want me to post the adaccount.py file ? It's huge.

Comment: That adaccount.py file is downloaded from facebook, I don't see why there would be a bug ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57437904/need-to-know-why-im-getting-invalid-syntax-error-for-from-facebookads-adobjects):

The version of your **API** and **Python** are not compatible.

The error is caused by the parameter called `async` from `get_insights()`, which since Python 3.7 isn't allowed anymore since `async` is now a reserved keyword of python.

**Solution**: Use an older Python version (**<3.7**) or use a version of the API that is 
compatible with Python 3.7.

Comment: How should I go about getting an older verison of python ? I just tried using homebrew and pyenv to download python 3.6 and I ran the SAMPLE_CODE.py and it gave me a bunch of new errors

Answer (score 1):

Try `facebook_business` instead of `facebookads`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58817369/10332176).